# How to enable/disable audio on camera video stream using ONVIF

Tags: audio, onvif

I'm really stumped here.  I'm trying to use the ONVIF protocol to enable/disable audio on RTSP streams from an IP camera.  If you wish to disable audio on a profile, you should first send 'removeAudioEncoderConfiguration' to remove the audio codec, then send 'removeAudioSourceConfiguration' on the same profile.

So I do this for ALL profiles on the camera (there happen to be 5).  However, the RTSP stream still has audio in it.

This is happening on a Uniview camera.  If I do the same sequence of messages on a Techwin device I have, then the audio is disabled.

Similarly if I try to enable audio on a profile, I do the reverse operations.  Again, the Techwin adds the audio, but the Uniview does not.

The responses I received to my ONVIF messages are always 'OK'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set `ForcePersistent = true`. It's the only thing that pop in my mind reading your question. However, try to post your code, maybe something's wrong there.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please use *"Add a comment"* for this. Thank you.